# Line of individual divs sliding left when the browser is resized

Tags: html, css, header, centering

I am building a Set Generator app that is for musicians to use to see the songs the band is going to play on the gig, in the order they are to be played.  Included in each set is the song title, the song key, and specific information depending upon who is logged in to the app.  I am using Bootstrap for CSS as well as a local stylesheet (style.css).  I am also endeavoring to use the Flexbox framework.  I am developing this in VS Code.

On the main User page, I have a page title, a couple of controls (date and set#), and when set, they are to display a line item below a "header" for each song in that set.  My problem is with the list header.

Here is the div in question.

```
<div class="flex-container row m-2">
    <div style=>
        <div class="table-hdr col-8">Title</div>
    <div class="table-hdr">Key</div>
    <div class="table-hdr">Fantom</div>
    <div class="table-hdr">DI</div>
    </div>
</div>


Image 1.

Which causes the line to look like the first image above.  However, when I stretch the window, whether inside of VS Code or in a browser window, the second image.

Image 2.
```

I have successfully gotten the other elements above this header to stay where they are and are adaptive.  This line, however, has 4 individual divs, one for each header element (title, key, Fantom, and Di), and they are styled using table-hdr class, and one col-8 class.  This cause them to stay together in a row.  The problem is the shifting of the row to the left when the browser is resized.

I have tried some of the bootstrap stylings, such as justify-content variations, tables, you name it.  Getting nowhere fast.  I am using all the standard media queries:

```
/* Media Queries */
/* Create four equal columns that floats next to each other */
.column {
    float: left;
    width: 25%;
}

  /* On screens that are 992px wide or less, go from four columns to two columns */
@media screen and (max-width: 992px) {
    .column {
        width: 50%;
    }
}

  /* On screens that are 600px wide or less, make the columns stack on top of each other instead of next to each other */
    @media screen and (max-width: 600px) {
    .column {
        width: 100%;
    }
}
```

I have also tried display:inline-block, position: absolute, position: relative, and others.